# Why quantity Box is incremented by 2 every time on click of increment or decrement button

Tags: jquery, magento

I am new to Magento. Please forgive me to ask this question but i need really help as I am unable to figure it out.

I am using classishop theme in magento. My problem is that I have added ADD TO CART button with quantity box on list.phtml page. I have done following task:

first I have added this:

```
<div class="quantity">

<input type="button" value="" id="add1" class="plus" title="<?php echo $this->__('Increments here No. of Qty') ?>" onclick="setQty(<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>, '<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>');"/>
<input type="text" name="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" id="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getMinimalQty($_product) ?>" onkeyup="setQty(<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>, '<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Input here No. of Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
<input type="button" value="" id="minus1" class="minus" title="<?php echo $this->__('Decrement here No. of Qty') ?>" onclick="setQty(<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>, '<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>');"/>
</div>
<span id="cart_button_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><button type="button" class="addToCart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"></span></button></span>
</form>
```

The second thing I added a jquery code:

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(".plus").click(function()
{
        var currentVal = parseInt(jQuery(this).next(".qty").val());
        if (!currentVal || currentVal=="" || currentVal == "NaN") currentVal = 1;
                   jQuery(this).next(".qty").val(currentVal + 1);

    });

    jQuery(".minus").click(function()
    {
        var currentVal = parseInt(jQuery(this).prev(".qty").val());
        if (currentVal == "NaN") currentVal = 0;
        if (currentVal > 1)
        {
            jQuery(this).prev(".qty").val(currentVal - 1);
        }
        // Ajax save here??
    });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setQty(id, url) {
var qty = document.getElementById('qty_' + id).value;
document.getElementById('cart_button_' + id).innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="addToCart" onclick="setLocation(\'' + url + 'qty/' + qty + ')"></button>';  
}
</script>
```

The Problem is that when I click on + or - button then the quantity box value is incremented or decremented by 2. Please help me out to figure this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I put it into a fiddle and its working correctly, the problem must be somewhere else in your code - http://jsfiddle.net/1p97me9d/

Comment: I found the solution. I just put the script into footer.phtml file and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution as I put the jquery script into footer.phtml file as It was running 2 times.

Now its working fine